# How to choose the weights for a cluster analysis with gower's distances

Tags: clustering

I am doing a mixed data cluster analysis with 32 variables. For this reason i chose to use gower's distances for clustering. The variables can be divided into three groups with different sizes. The group sizes are 5, 7 and 20. With a weighting of 1 for all variables, the last group would have a greater overall weighting than the other two groups because of its sizw. How do I select the weights of the individual variables so that all groups are equally weighted? I was thinking of dividing the weighting by the number of variables, so for

1. Group 1: 1/5
2. Group 2: 1/7
3. Group 3: 1/20.

Does this approach make sense? According to Chat-gpt I should rather divide by the square root of the group size, so

1. Group 1: 1/5^0.5
2. Group 2: 1/7^0.5
3. Group 3: 1/20^0.5.

Is this approach better? If so, why should I take the root? I didn't see any squaring in the formula for calculating the gower distance.

Add to that the fact that groups 1 and 2 in my data set are metric, whereas group 3 is binary. As far as I understand, categorical variables have a greater effect on Gower's distances than metric variables, even with equal weighting. As a result, my cluster analysis is very much skewed in favor of the group 3 variables, which is why it is important for me to add weighting.

Thanks in advance